# Show Manufacturer Country Name of Product Page of Prestashop 1.6 Ecommerce

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to php. can any one guide me how to show Manufacturer country name on Product Page. I have done several experiments like overriding ProductController.php and other trick but fail. I also tried different solution on internet but cannot succeed up to. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a manufacturer can has more than one address. This code gets the country only from first address.

Override controller `ProductController` at `override/controllers/front`:

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        if (!$this->errors) {
            $manufacturer = new Manufacturer((int)$this->product->id_manufacturer, $this->context->language->id);
            $manufacturerAddress = $manufacturer->getAddresses($this->context->language->id);

            if (isset($manufacturerAddress) && $manufacturerAddress[0]['country']) {
                $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                    'manufacturer_country' => $manufacturerAddress[0]['country'],
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And print it in your TPL:

```
{$manufacturer_country|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

Remember to delete `cache/class_index.php` when you override the controller.